# How to catch custom exception?

Tags: kotlin, testing, integration-testing, project-reactor

I'm working on a reactive Kotlin project, I wrote a test where, when information is missing (layout), it will trigger a custom exception.
Debugging I saw that the exception is thrown during the test but instead of the test passing, I receive an error.

this is the test

```
//bookIntegrationTest 

@Test
    fun `cathErrorWhen try getBook without layout`() {

        val context = "HUB"
        val existingBook = bookWithoutLayout(
            status = "ACTIVE"          
        )
     
        val rules = arrayOf(
            "test1",
            "test2"
        )

        StepVerifier.create(createBookFlux(existingBook))
            .assertNext {
                webClient.get().uri { uriBuilder ->
                    uriBuilder.path(BOOK_URL).path("/{type}")
                        .queryParam("rules", rules)
                        .build(existingBook.type)
                }
                    .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.books.v1+json"))
                    .header(CUSTOMER_ID_HEADER, "customerId")
                    .header(USER_ID_HEADER, System.nanoTime().toString())
                    .exchange()
                    .expectStatus().isOk
                    .expectBodyList(GetBookResponse::class.java)
                    .contains(existingBook.toBookDocument().copy(id = it.id).toBookResponse())//InvalidRequiredDataException
            }
              .expectError(InvalidRequiredDataException::class.java)
            .verify()

    }

data class GetBookResponse(
    val id: String? = null,
    val title: String,
    val img: String,
    val extras: Map<String, String>? = null,
    val layout: LayoutItem,//IS NOT NULLABLE
    val filters: Map<String, String>? = null,
    val priority: Int? = null,
)

fun BookDocument.toBookResponse(): GetBookResponse =
    GetBookResponse(
        id = this.id,
        title = this.title,
        img = this.img,
        extras = this.extras,
        layout = this.layout?.toLayoutDocument() ?: throw InvalidRequiredDataException("layout"),//HERE
        filters = this.filters,
        priority = this.priority,
    )
```

Debugging the test I notice that the exception is thrown as expected
layout = this.layout?.toLayoutDocument() ?: throw InvalidRequiredDataException("layout"),//HERE

when i run the test
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation failed (failed running expectation on signal [onNext(PostBookResponseV2(id=65534881d23cb76e8c707001))]
with [us.book.core.exception.InvalidRequiredDataException]:
layout is null)
at reactor.test.MessageFormatter.assertionError(MessageFormatter.java:115)
..
..

It seems to me that it works the way I implemented it, the error is being expected here: PostBookResponseV2
but it really happens here, on BookMapper

```
fun BookDocument.toBookResponse(): GetBookResponse =
 GetBookResponse(
..
             layout = this.layout?.toLayoutDocument() ?: throw InvalidRequiredDataException("layout")
..
    )
```

Comment: What is `PostBookResponseV2`?  You don't show the source for this and how it is used in your code.